# customizing velocity's DataSourceResourceLoader?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, velocity

I am using apache velocity template to format the content then send the mails. But template content will be availabe in `database table`. For this we can use `DataSourceResourceLoader`.
But it works with predefined database table format and it gets only `templateContent`. But i want to get few more columns from the same table using the same `DataSourceResourceLoader`.
How can i do that?

Please find below code from `DataSourceResourceLoader` where it gets only one column.

```
public synchronized InputStream getResourceStream(final String name)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException
    {
        if (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("DataSourceResourceLoader: Template name was empty or null");
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try
        {
            conn = openDbConnection();
            ps = getStatement(conn, templateColumn, tableName, keyColumn, name);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next())
            {
                InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream(templateColumn);
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("DataSourceResourceLoader: "
                                                        + "template column for '"
                                                        + name + "' is null");
                }

                return new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("DataSourceResourceLoader: "
                                                    + "could not find resource '"
                                                    + name + "'");

            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            String msg = "DataSourceResourceLoader: database problem while getting resource '"
                         + name + "': ";

            log.error(msg, sqle);
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
        }
        catch (NamingException ne)
        {
            String msg = "DataSourceResourceLoader: database problem while getting resource '"
                         + name + "': ";

            log.error(msg, ne);
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            closeResultSet(rs);
            closeStatement(ps);
            closeDbConnection(conn);
        }
    }
```

In above code `InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream(templateColumn);` is retrieved and returned. Now i need to get few more columns. How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You're very vague in what you're trying to achieve.  The `DataSourceResourceLoader` will only return the template content and the last modified date.  What other columns would you want?

Comment: i can create a table with few more columns and i need to access them..can i add few more columns to the same table and retrieve them? Thanks!

Comment: But why do you need to access them when getting the template content? Wouldn't it make more sense to get additional data inside the controller and pass those values in as values to be used in the template?